# How to mark some but not all emails in Gmail as read

Tags: gmail

I have a number of older emails in Gmail which are unread which I'd like to make read but I don't want to mark recent unread emails as read. Can I mark all emails from a specific date to be marked read without manually finding each one?

Answer (score 1):

The same way you'd do any bulk action on email messages: Search first.

Assuming you want to find all of the messages from before April 1 and mark them read:

1. search Gmail for `before:2019-04-01`
2. click the checkbox at the top of the list to select all of the visible messages
3. if you have more than 1 page of results, you'll get a message similar to "All 50 conversations on this page are selected. Select all conversations that match this search" where "Select all conversations..." is a link. Click that link to choose **all** matching messages
4. Choose your action. "Mark as read" should be one of the buttons at the top, among others. There are other actions in the "More" menu

There are a lot of [search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190).

Comment: Many thanks. I added "before:2019-10-01 label:unread"  and all the unread messages came up. I then clicked the open envelope icon to change them to read.